# Sending event to single user in Microsoft Teams with Proactive Message

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to build an app with Microsoft Teams which has proactive message. My goal is to send event notifications to a particular user. With incoming webhooks, it is possible to send event message to a channel in Teams but I'm looking to send the message to a single user. Based on the Microsoft documentation, it is possible using the bot proactive message. It will used the bot as middleman but is Microsoft Bot Framework is the only way to do it? Is it possible to communicate to Teams using different service or bot platform? I believe that the Microsoft Bot Framework requires to register the bot with the Azure service. If I don't have that, is there other alternative or maybe way to send events to a particular user and not everyone in a channel?

I hope you understand the scenario and give me some advice.

Thank you.

Comment: To my knowledge, a bot is your only option for sending directly to an individual user

Comment: Hi. thanks for the response. Do you have experience with it? Do you know if I could use different way instead of using the Microsoft Bot Framework?

Comment: I'll post a proper answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this using a bot, and I think it's the only practical way to send a message to  individual users from an app. I use it in a few projects, and it works fine. There are some throttle limits to be aware of if you're sending very high volumes.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer and I appreciate it. so basically, when you say 'bot' does it refer to Microsoft Bot Framework? Is it possible to use different bot framework service in Microsoft Teams or not?